# In this script, ~ is /root/. How to be in /home/name-of-the-user/?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash    

#become root
UID=$(id -u)
if [ x$UID != x0 ] 
then
    printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$0" "$@"
    exec sudo su -c "$cmd_str"
fi


mkdir ~/.D3GO/; 
cp -a `pwd`/viewright_backup/. ~/.D3GO/;

mkdir /opt/D3GO/;
cp `pwd`/D3GO /opt/D3GO/;
cp `pwd`/D3GO.png /opt/D3GO/;
cp `pwd`/D3GO.desktop /usr/share/applications/;
chmod +x /opt/D3GO/D3GO;
```

As you can see, because this uses ~, and the script is ran as root, it creats the folder.D3GO in the /root/ directory. Is it possible to create it in the home directory. For example, if the script is located in /home/user/Downloads/, it should create the directory in home/user/. If it's located in /home/user2/Downloads/dir/, it should create it in /home/user2/ etc. Is this possible? Thanks!

Maybe something like:

```
#!/bin/bash    

#remember the username
user = $(whoami);

#become root
UID=$(id -u)
if [ x$UID != x0 ] 
then
    printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$0" "$@"
    exec sudo su -c "$cmd_str"
fi


mkdir /home/`$user`/.D3GO/; 
cp -a `pwd`/viewright_backup/. /home/`$user`/.D3GO/;
```

Comment: Why are you using `su` to install into the current user's home directory?

Comment: Because I also need to access /usr/share/applications/

Comment: Then you should escalate to root *only* for the part of the install for which you write to `/usr/share/applications`, not for all of it. Otherwise, you're creating files in a user's home directory they don't have permissions to write to -- and that's a good way to have angry users.

Comment: By the way, `sudo su` is generally bad practice. `sudo` can do everything `su` can, so you don't need to use both together; most uses of `sudo su` can be replaced with `sudo -i`.

Comment: you don't have to use `` if you are using $user. Just say /home/$user/.D3GO - I would also suggest to use $USER for setting user variable.

Comment: (also, most operating systems frown on installing into `/usr` except through the system's package manager; `/usr/local` and `/opt` are more appropriate for local packages bypassing the management system).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/493325/80864

Answer (score 1):

```
if [ "$UID" != 0 ] 
then
    printf -v set_home_prefix 'HOME=%q; ' "$HOME"
    printf -v cmd_str '%q ' "$0" "$@"
    exec sudo su -c "$set_home_prefix $cmd_str"
fi
```

I took the liberty of correcting the invalid quoting you were given in the answer you accepted on the other question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question literally:

`sudo -E` preserves environment variables (although some variables may be overwritten by the new shell).

```
export MY_HOME=$HOME
. . .

exec sudo -E su -c "$cmd_str"
```

Then you can reference `$MY_HOME` in the script and it should be set to the original user's `$HOME`.

But I agree with the comment from @CharlesDuffy, you should `sudo` for individual commands you need to run. If you do that, then arguments to the `sudo` command are substituted from the original shell.

For example:

```
sudo cp -a `pwd`/viewright_backup/. $HOME/.D3GO/;
```

This uses the non-root user's `$HOME`, because the variable substitution happens before the `sudo` command is executed.

Comment: ...or `sudo MY_HOME="$HOME" ...`, which explicitly exports a specific variable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes good point, he may *not* want to export all env variables.